# Largest Heap used in a managed environment? (.net/java)

Tags: c#, java, .net, memory, memory-management

What is the largest heap you have personally used in a managed environment such as Java or .NET?  What were some of the performance issues you ran into, and did you end up getting a diminishing returns the larger the heap was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on a 64-bit .Net system that typically uses 9-12 GB, and sometimes as much as 20GB. I have not seen any performance problems even while garbage collecting, and I have been looking hard as I was not expecting it to work so well.

An earlier version hung on to some objects for too long resulting in occasional GCs that freed up 3GB+. Even then, there was no noticeable impact on performance. The system is running on a 16-core server with 32GB RAM, which probably helps...

Answer (score 1):

In .Net, on Windows 32-bit, You can only really get to about 1.4 GB of memory usage before things start getting really screwy (out of memory exceptions).   This is due to a limitation in 32 bit windows that limits a single process to using more than 2 GB of RAM.  There is /3GB switch you can put in your boot.ini, but that will only bring you a little bit further.  If you want to use lots of memory, you should seriously consider running on a 64 bit version of windows.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a production application with 6 GB of memory. You'll need a 64-bit box as well for the JVM to be able to address that much. 
The garbage collector is really the only thing (that I've found so far) where performance degrades with size, and then only if you manually kick off a System.GC, which forces the JVM to bring everything to a screeching halt as it traverses 6 GB worth of objects. Takes a good 20 seconds, too. The default GC behavior does not do this, BTW, you have to be dumb enough to make it do that. Also worth researching JVM tuning at this size.

You can also find things like distributed and clustered JVMs, sorry, don't have any good references as I didn't look into this option too closely, although I did find references to larger installations.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you mean by heap,  but if you mean memory used, I have used quite a bit, 2GB+. I have a web app that does image processing and it requires loading 2 large scan files into memory to do analysis.

There were performance issues. Windows would swap out lots of ram, and then that would create a lot of page faults. There was never any need for anymore than 2 images at a time as all requests were gainst those images (I only allowed  1 session per image set at a time)

For instance, to setup the files for initial viewing would take about 5 seconds. Doing simple analysis and zooming would be fairly fast once in memory, in the order of .1 to .5 seconds.

I still had to optimize, so I ended up preparsung the files and chopping into smaller peices and worked only with the peices that were required by the user at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used from 2GB to 5GB of memory in java, but usually when I get to more than 2GB I really start thinking about memory optimization. Diminishing returns can vary from not optimizing when it's necessary because you have a lot of memory, to not having memory available for the OS/Disk caches (which can help your application overall).

For Java, I recommend watching your memory usage per generation over time. Do you create a lot of temporary objects or have long-lasting objects that consume a lot of memory? A lot of optimization of memory can be done when knowing those things.